# Should the exception thrown by boost::asio::io_service::run() be caught?

Tags: c++, boost, exception, boost-asio

`boost::asio::io_service::run()` throws a `boost::system::system_error` exception in case of error. Should I handle this exception? If so, how?

my main.cpp code is something like this:

```
main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service queue;
    boost::asio::io_service::work work(queue);
    {
      // set some handlers...
      **queue.run();**
    }
    // join some workers...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It all depends.  Can you recover from it if it does?  Also do you know how to catch exceptions?

Comment: @NathanOliver in async settings, in particular, it is about knowing whether an exception in one of the many flows should stop the entire multiplexing service. In 90% of cases, that's not desired. Regular control flow does not apply in the proactor model

Answer (score 9):

Yes.

It is documented that exceptions thrown from completion handlers are propagated. So you need to handle them as appropriate for your application.

In many cases, this would be looping and repeating the `run()` until it exits without an error.

In our code base I have something like

```
static void m_asio_event_loop(boost::asio::io_service& svc, std::string name) {
    // http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service.effect_of_exceptions_thrown_from_handlers
    for (;;) {
        try {
            svc.run();
            break; // exited normally
        } catch (std::exception const &e) {
            logger.log(LOG_ERR) << "[eventloop] An unexpected error occurred running " << name << " task: " << e.what();
        } catch (...) {
            logger.log(LOG_ERR) << "[eventloop] An unexpected error occurred running " << name << " task";
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the documentation link http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service.effect_of_exceptions_thrown_from_handlers