# Calling boost::asio::io_service run function from multiple threads

Tags: c++11, boost-asio

In my server application there is a pool of threads calling the io_service run() function. When a handler throws an exception the run function throws that exception too. Multiple threads call the run function in a try catch block. To restart the event handler I need to call run again but the documentation stated that restart() has to be called first. Restarting the io_service must assure that all run calls has been finished. How can I do that when other threads are still calling the run function?

Comment: It's all `run` calls for that specific `io_service` object.

Comment: There is only one io_service object and multiple threads call run on that single object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To restart the event handler I need to call run again but the documentation stated that restart() has to be called first.

**No** the documentation does **not** say that. You need to reset once the service *had run out of work/been stopped*. You did neither, so you do not need reset there.

Simply do as explained in this post [Should the exception thrown by boost::asio::io_service::run() be caught?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500818/should-the-exception-thrown-by-boostasioio-servicerun-be-caught/44500924#44500924) (which links to the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service.effect_of_exceptions_thrown_from_handlers))