# Boost:asio and async in multi-threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, asio, stdasync

I need to call method which is a request for a remote server. After that i want to wait for an answer, and waiting is not blocked by other asynchronous function/objects(timers for example).

Method got_response(...) tells user that he got an answer from remote server, also method gets entry data which we got as an answer. Below I got my solution, but sometimes timer can be called in single thread, which will lead to method got_response() hanging.

How can I call timer to be guaranteed in other thread for answer simulation. Is there any other solution to my problem?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

namespace io = boost::asio;

struct Reply
{
    atomic<bool> ready;
    atomic<int> result;

    future<void> future_result;

    Reply()
    {
        ready = false;
        result = 0;
    }

    void call()
    {
        cout << "retry called!" << endl;
        future_result = async([&]()
                              {
                                  while (!ready)
                                  {
                                      this_thread::yield();
                                  }
                              });
    }

    int get()
    {
        future_result.wait();
        return result.load();
    }

    void got_response(int res)
    {
        result = res;
        ready = true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Reply reply;
    reply.call();

    io::io_context context(4);

    io::steady_timer timer1(context, std::chrono::seconds(2));
    timer1.async_wait([&](const boost::system::error_code &ec)
                      { cout << "timer 1, thread name: " << this_thread::get_id() << endl; });

    io::steady_timer timer2(context, std::chrono::seconds(3));
    timer2.async_wait([&](const boost::system::error_code &ec)
                      {
                          cout << "timer 2, thread name: " << this_thread::get_id() << endl;
                          cout << reply.get() << endl;
                      });

    io::steady_timer timer3(context, std::chrono::seconds(10));
    timer3.async_wait([&](const boost::system::error_code &ec)
                      {
                          cout << "timer 3, thread name: " << this_thread::get_id() << endl;
                          reply.got_response(1337);
                      });

    vector<thread> threads;
    auto count = 2;

    for (int n = 0; n < count; ++n)
    {
        threads.emplace_back([&]
                             { context.run(); });
    }

    for (auto &th : threads)
    {
        th.join();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
retry called!
timer 1, thread name: 140712511198784
timer 2, thread name: 140712519591488
timer 3, thread name: 140712511198784
1337
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. This overcomplicating on several levels.

- futures can have typed return values (that's actually the whole point of a future over synchronization primitives)
- the fturue can signal the readiness **with a value**, no need to duplicate the readiness into a `bool` and then copy the result somewhere
- this has me  confused:

  ```
   int get()
   {
       _fut.wait();
       return _result.load();
   }
  ```

  It awaits the future, then returns the `_result`, you know what you invented `_ready` for?
- Do you realize that `std::async` is not part of Boost ASIO? In fact, it doesn't work well with it because, as you correctly notice, it introduces (unspecified numbers of)  threads. In general my advice is not to use `std::async` (it's hard to use correctly) and certainly never when using ASIO
- When you see the same variables name var1, var2, var3 it's time to refactor your code (into functions or classes if it includes data members):

  ```
   std::deque<io::steady_timer> timers;

   for (int i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
       auto& timer = timers.emplace_back(context, std::chrono::seconds(1+i));
       timer.async_wait([i](error_code ec) {
           std::cout << "timer " << i
                     << ", thread name: " << std::this_thread::get_id()
                     << std::endl;
       });
   }
  ```
- instead of a vector of threads, consider `boost::thread_group` or indeed `boost::asio::thread_pool`.
- If you manually run the IO threads, remember to handle exceptions ([Should the exception thrown by boost::asio::io_service::run() be caught?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500818/should-the-exception-thrown-by-boostasioio-servicerun-be-caught/44500924#44500924)), so

  ```
   boost::thread_group threads;
   for (int n = 0; n < 2; ++n) {
       threads.create_thread([&] { context.run(); });
   }

   threads.join_all();
  ```

  Or indeed

  ```
   io::thread_pool context(2);
   context.join();
  ```
- This is **very** inefficient

  ```
   while (!_ready) {
       std::this_thread::yield();
   }
  ```

  Just set the future value to signify it's ready:
- `using namespace std` is generally not a good idea ([Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice))

### Demo

Here's my expanded but simplified take on the question code:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62daf9a81a121dbf)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <deque>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
namespace io = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using boost::system::error_code;

// not very useful in practice, but for debug output in main
std::ostream& debug(error_code);
template <typename Fut> bool is_ready(Fut const& fut) {
    return fut.wait_for(0s) == std::future_status::ready;
}

int main() {
    std::promise<int>  reply;
    std::shared_future got_value = reply.get_future();

    io::thread_pool              context(2);
    std::deque<io::steady_timer> timers;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
        timers //
            .emplace_back(context, i * 1s)
            .async_wait([&got_value](error_code ec) {
                if (is_ready(got_value))
                    debug(ec) << " Reply:" << got_value.get() << std::endl;
                else
                    debug(ec) << " (reply not ready)" << std::endl;
            });
    }

    timers //
        .emplace_back(context, 4'500ms)
        .async_wait([&reply](error_code ec) {
            debug(ec) << " setting value" << std::endl;
            reply.set_value(1337);
        });

    context.join();
}
    
int friendly_thread_id() {
    return std::hash<std::thread::id>{}(std::this_thread::get_id()) % 256;
}

#include <iomanip>
std::ostream& debug(error_code ec) {
    auto        now           = std::chrono::system_clock::now;
    static auto program_start = now();
    return std::cout //
        << ((now() - program_start) / 1ms) << "ms\t"
        << "thread:" << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::showbase
        << std::setw(2) << friendly_thread_id() << std::dec << " ";
}


#include <iomanip>
std::ostream& debug(error_code ec) {
    auto        now           = std::chrono::system_clock::now;
    static auto program_start = now();
    return std::cout //
        << ((now() - program_start) / 1ms) << "ms\t"
        << "thread:" << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::showbase
        << std::setw(2) << pretty_thread_id() << std::dec << " ";
}
```

Prints

```
0ms     thread:0x5f  (reply not ready)
999ms   thread:0xf3  (reply not ready)
1999ms  thread:0x5f  (reply not ready)
2999ms  thread:0x5f  (reply not ready)
3499ms  thread:0xf3  setting value
3999ms  thread:0x5f  Reply:1337
4999ms  thread:0xf3  Reply:1337
5999ms  thread:0xf3  Reply:1337
6999ms  thread:0xf3  Reply:1337
7999ms  thread:0xf3  Reply:1337
8999ms  thread:0xf3  Reply:1337
```

Comment: A version that only requires 1 timer and has many background "tasks" running at randomized intervals: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3657fe53be68d5d

Comment: _(Only after I posted my answer did I realize that you meant "Asio and std::async" not, "Asio and asynchronous work". I hope you find my answer code helpful though)_