# Simple client/server using C++/boost socket works under Windows but fails under Linux

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to write a very simple client/server app with `boost::socket`. I need a server to run and a single client to connect, send data, disconnect and possibly reconnect later and repeat.

The code reduced to the minimum is here:

Server app:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class TheServer
{
public:
    TheServer(int port) : m_port(port)
    {
        m_pIOService = new boost::asio::io_service;

        m_pThread = new boost::thread(boost::bind<void>(&TheServer::run, this));

        listenForNewConnection();
    }
    ~TheServer()
    {
        m_bContinueReading = false;

        m_pIOService->stop();
        m_pThread->join();

        delete m_pThread;
        delete m_pSocket;
        delete m_pAcceptor;
        delete m_pIOService;
    }

    void listenForNewConnection()
    {
        if (m_pSocket)
            delete m_pSocket;
        if (m_pAcceptor)
            delete m_pAcceptor;
        
        // start new acceptor operation
        m_pSocket = new tcp::socket(*m_pIOService);
        m_pAcceptor = new tcp::acceptor(*m_pIOService, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), m_port));

        std::cout << "Starting async_accept" << std::endl;

        m_pAcceptor->async_accept(*m_pSocket,
            boost::bind<void>(&TheServer::readSession, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void readSession(boost::system::error_code error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            std::cout << "Connection established" << std::endl;
            while ( m_bContinueReading )
            {
                static unsigned char buffer[1000];
                boost::system::error_code error;
                size_t length = m_pSocket->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(&buffer, 1000), error);
                if (!error && length != 0)
                {
                    std::cout << "Received " << buffer << std::endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "Received error, connection likely closed by peer" << std::endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            std::cout << "Connection closed" << std::endl;
            listenForNewConnection();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Connection error" << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "Ending readSession" << std::endl;
    }

    void run()
    {
        while (m_bContinueReading)
            m_pIOService->run_one();
        std::cout << "Exiting run thread" << std::endl;
    }

    bool m_bContinueReading = true;
    boost::asio::io_service* m_pIOService = NULL;
    tcp::socket* m_pSocket = NULL;
    tcp::acceptor* m_pAcceptor = NULL;
    boost::thread* m_pThread = NULL;
    int m_port;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    TheServer* server = new TheServer(1900);

    std::cout << "Press Enter to quit" << std::endl;
    std::string sGot;
    getline(std::cin, sGot);

    delete server;

    return 0;
}
```

Client app:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "Starting client" << std::endl;

    using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
    boost::asio::io_service* m_pIOService = NULL;
    tcp::socket* m_pSocket = NULL;

    try
    {
        m_pIOService = new boost::asio::io_service;

        std::stringstream sPort;
        sPort << 1900;

        tcp::resolver resolver(*m_pIOService);
        tcp::resolver::query query(tcp::v4(), "localhost", sPort.str());
        tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

        m_pSocket = new tcp::socket(*m_pIOService);
        m_pSocket->connect(*iterator);

        std::cout << "Client conected" << std::endl;

        std::string hello = "Hello World";
        boost::asio::write( *m_pSocket, boost::asio::buffer(hello.data(), hello.size()) );
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(100));
        hello += "(2)";
        boost::asio::write(*m_pSocket, boost::asio::buffer(hello.data(), hello.size()));

    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        delete m_pSocket;
        m_pSocket = NULL;
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I use non-blocking async_accept to be able to cleanly stop the server when Enter is pressed.

Under Windows, it works perfectly fine, I run the server, it outputs:

```
Starting async_accept
Press Enter to quit
```

For each client app run, it outpts:

```
Starting client
Client conected
```

and server app outputs:

```
Connection established
Received Hello World
Received Hello World(2)
Received error, connection likely closed by peer
Connection closed
Starting async_accept
Ending readSession
```

Then when I press Enter in server app console, it outputs `Exiting run thread` and cleanly stops.

Now, when I compile this same code under Linux, the client outputs the same as under Windows, but nothing happens on the server side...

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: This is undefined behavior due to broken thread synchronization. Multiple access to the same objects from multiple execution threads, without synchronizing the threads correctly. It also isn't helpful that the shown code appears to suffer from the common "Pointless Use Of Pointers" malady.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik +100 - I've spent a small hour going through the issues. I think the most obvious problem is #2, but the rest is best not ignored :)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Sorry for having produce such an ugly code. It was compilation of other SO posts + some old code I had. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many questionable elements.

1. There is a classical data race on `m_bContinueReading`. You write from another thread, but the other thread may never see the change because of the data race.
2. The second race condition is likely your problem:

   ```
   m_pThread = new boost::thread(boost::bind<void>(&TheServer::run, this));
   listenForNewConnection();
   ```

   Here the `run` thread may complete before you ever post the first work. You can use a work-guard to prevent this. In your specific code you would already fix it by reordering the lines:

   ```
   listenForNewConnection();
   m_pThread = new boost::thread(boost::bind<void>(&TheServer::run, this));
   ```

   > *I would not do this, because I would not have those statements in my constructor body. See below for the work guard solution*
3. There is a lot of raw pointer handling and new/delete going on, which merely invites errors.
4. You use the `buffer` assuming that it is NUL-terminated. This is especially unwarranted because you use `read_some` which will read partial messages as they arrive on the wire.
5. You use a `static` buffer while the code may have different instances of the class. This is very false optimization. Instead, prevent all the allocations! Combining with the previous item:

   ```
   char buffer[1000];
   while (m_bContinueReading) {
       size_t length = m_Socket.read_some(asio::buffer(&buffer, 1000), ec);

       std::cout << "Received " << length << " (" << quoted(std::string(buffer, length)) << "), "
                 << ec.message() << std::endl;
       if (ec.failed())
           break;
   }
   ```
6. You start a new acceptor always, where there is no need: a single acceptor can accept as many connections as you wish. In fact, the method shown runs into the problems

   - that lingering connections can prevent the new acceptor from binding to the same port. You could *also* alleviate that with

     ```
     m_Acceptor.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
     ```
   - the destroyed acceptor may have backlogged connections, which are discarded

   Typically you want to support concurrent connection, so you can split of a "readSession" and immediately accept the next connection. Now, strangely your code seems to expect clients to be connected until the server is prompted to shutdown (from the console) **but** after that you somehow start listening to new connections (even though you know the service will be stopping, and `m_bContinueReading` will remain `false`).

   In the grand scheme of things, you don't want to destroy the acceptor unless something invalidated it. In practice this is rare (e.g. on Linux the acceptor will happily survive disabling/re-enabling the network adaptor).
7. you have spurious explicit template arguments (`bind<void>`). This is an anti-pattern and may lead to subtle problems
8. similar with the buffer (just say `asio::buffer(buffer)` and no longer have correctness concerns. In fact, don't use C-style arrays:

   ```
   std::array<char, 1000> buffer;
   size_t n = m_Socket.read_some(asio::buffer(buffer), ec);

   std::cout << "Received " << n << " " << quoted(std::string(buffer.data(), n))
             << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
   ```
9. Instead of running a manual `run_one()` loop (where you [forget to handle exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44500924/85371)), consider "just" letting the service `run()`. Then you can `.cancel()` the acceptor to let the service run out of work.

   In fact, this subtlety isn't required in your code, since your code already forces "ungraceful" shutdown anyways:

   ```
   m_IOService.stop(); // nuclear option
   m_Thread.join();
   ```

   More gentle would be e.g.

   ```
   m_Acceptor.cancel();
   m_Socket.cancel();
   m_Thread.join();
   ```

   In which case you can respond to the completion `error_code == error::operation_aborted` to stop the session/accept loop.

   > Technically, you may be able to do away with the boolean flag altogether.
   > I keep it because it allows us to handle multiple session-per-thread in
   > "fire-and-forget" manner.
10. In the client you have many of the same problems, and also a gotcha where
    you only look at the first resolver result (assuming there was one),
    ignoring the rest. You can use `asio::connect` instead of
    `m_Socket.connect` to try all resolved entries

Addressing the majority of these issues, simplifying the code:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57748be35b5e5e85)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using boost::system::error_code;

class TheServer {
  public:
    TheServer(int port) : m_port(port) {
        m_Acceptor.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
        do_accept();
    }

    ~TheServer() {
        m_shutdownRequested = true;
        m_Work.reset(); // release the work-guard
        m_Acceptor.cancel();
        m_Thread.join();
    }

  private:
    void do_accept() {
        std::cout << "Starting async_accept" << std::endl;

        m_Acceptor.async_accept( //
            m_Socket, boost::bind(&TheServer::on_accept, this, asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void on_accept(error_code ec) {
        if (!ec) {
            std::cout << "Connection established " << m_Socket.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;

            // leave session running in the background:
            std::thread(&TheServer::read_session_thread, this, std::move(m_Socket)).detach();

            do_accept(); // and immediately accept new connection(s)
        } else {
            std::cout << "Connection error (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Ending readSession" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void read_session_thread(tcp::socket sock) {
        std::array<char, 1000> buffer;

        for (error_code ec;;) {
            size_t n = sock.read_some(asio::buffer(buffer), ec);
            std::cout << "Received " << n << " " << quoted(std::string(buffer.data(), n)) << " ("
                      << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;

            if (ec.failed() || m_shutdownRequested)
                break;
        }

        std::cout << "Connection closed" << std::endl;
    }

    void thread_func() {
        // http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service.effect_of_exceptions_thrown_from_handlers
        for (;;) {
            try {
                m_IOService.run();
                break; // exited normally
            } catch (std::exception const& e) {
                std::cerr << "[eventloop] error: " << e.what();
            } catch (...) {
                std::cerr << "[eventloop] unexpected error";
            }
        }

        std::cout << "Exiting service thread" << std::endl;
    }

    std::atomic_bool m_shutdownRequested{false};

    uint16_t                                m_port;
    asio::io_service                        m_IOService;
    boost::optional<asio::io_service::work> m_Work{m_IOService};
    tcp::socket                             m_Socket{m_IOService};
    tcp::acceptor                           m_Acceptor{m_IOService, tcp::endpoint{tcp::v4(), m_port}};
    std::thread                             m_Thread{boost::bind(&TheServer::thread_func, this)};
};

constexpr uint16_t s_port = 1900;

void run_server() {
    TheServer server(s_port);

    std::cout << "Press Enter to quit" << std::endl;
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}

void run_client() {
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Starting client" << std::endl;

    using asio::ip::tcp;

    try {
        asio::io_service m_IOService;

        tcp::resolver resolver(m_IOService);
        auto iterator = resolver.resolve("localhost", std::to_string(s_port));

        tcp::socket m_Socket(m_IOService);
        connect(m_Socket, iterator);

        std::cout << "Client connected" << std::endl;

        std::string hello = "Hello World";
        write(m_Socket, asio::buffer(hello));

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);

        hello += "(2)";
        write(m_Socket, asio::buffer(hello));
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char**) {
    if (argc>1)
        run_server();
    else
        run_client();
}
```

Comment: Ran out of steam before making dinner. Here's some more work modernizing to use executors and thread-pool instead of the manual everything: [Down to 90 lines of code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13fac7fca1047d05)

Comment: Ww, I was not expecting so many problems in the code (even if I was aware of some, did the MCVE a bit quickly yesterday I must admit). I'll test all this in the next days, thank you for your help.

Comment: I must admit my coe was a mess. Your is nce and it worked like a charm on all platforms!

Comment: Note that using `resolver.resolve(boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint{ boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), uint16_t(m_port) })` in `run_client` makes connection be established in 20ms instead of ~2000ms with `resolver.resolve("localhost", std::to_string(s_port))`! (only tested under Windows)

Comment: That makes sense because there's nothing to resolve. ~2s is a lot, you would need to check your DNS configuration to explain that (127.0.0.1 should really be in the hosts file). Of course, just spelling [`m_Socket.connect({{}, s_port});` was by far the simplest](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13fac7fca1047d05) and will perform better always :)