# boost TCP server does not correctly accept connections under Linux

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, tcpclient, tcpserver

I'm working on a client/server TCP applications. It works very well under Windows but I'm encountering problems under Linux: the server does not get notified when a new connection is established with the client (very rarely it is, but most often it is not).

I was able to isolate the issue in a very simple program. This program creates and runs a server (with its own `boost::asio::io_service`) accepting new connections and then establishs a connection from a client (also with its own `boost::asio::io_service`, as it would behave in seperate applications).

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

#include <assert.h>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> m_nextConnection;
std::atomic_bool m_continueServerThread = true;

void server_thread_func(boost::asio::io_service* service)
{
    // http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service.effect_of_exceptions_thrown_from_handlers
    while (m_continueServerThread) {
        try {
            service->run();
            // don't break, keep looping, else we may exit before a connection is actually established
            //break; // exited normally
        }
        catch (std::exception const& e) {
            std::cerr << "[eventloop] error: " << e.what();
        }
        catch (...) {
            std::cerr << "[eventloop] unexpected error";
        }
    }

}

void on_accept_connection(std::error_code ec)
{
    if (!ec)
    {
        std::cout << "SERVER ACCEPTED CONNECTION" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Reader connection error " << ec << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
    }
}

void do_accept_connection(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor& acceptor, boost::asio::io_service& service)
{
    m_nextConnection = std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket>(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(service));

    acceptor.async_accept(
            *m_nextConnection, boost::bind(on_accept_connection, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    auto endpoint = boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint{ boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 1900 };

    try
    {
        // start server:
        boost::asio::io_service IOServiceServer;
        
        boost::thread serverThread( boost::bind(server_thread_func,&IOServiceServer) );

        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(500));

        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor m_acceptor{ IOServiceServer, endpoint };

        // dunno if this is needed or not here
        //m_acceptor.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
        do_accept_connection(m_acceptor, IOServiceServer);

        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(500));

        // start client:
        boost::asio::io_service IOServiceClient;
        tcp::socket socket(IOServiceClient);

        std::cout << "Connecting socket..." << std::endl;        
        socket.connect(endpoint);
        std::cout << "Connected socket" << std::endl;

        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(500));

        // stop/close client:
        IOServiceClient.stop();
        socket.close();
        
        // stop server:
        IOServiceServer.stop();
        m_continueServerThread = false;
        serverThread.join();

        return 0;
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << "error: " << e.what();
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "unexpected error";
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Ran under Windows, this shows:

```
Connecting socket...
Connected socket
SERVER ACCEPTED CONNECTION
```

Ran under Linux, this only shows:

```
Connecting socket...
Connected socket
```

As you can see `on_accept_connection` is not being called, so the server does not get notified that a new connection was established.

Am I doing something wrong?

---

Edit: Also tried without m_nextConnection:

```
void on_accept_connection(std::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket)
{
    if (!ec)
    {
        std::cout << "SERVER ACCEPTED CONNECTION" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Reader connection error " << ec << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
    }
}

void do_accept_connection(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor& acceptor, boost::asio::io_service& service)
{
    acceptor.async_accept(service, [&](const std::error_code& ec, tcp::socket newSocket) {
        on_accept_connection(ec, std::move(newSocket));
        });
}
```

Does not solve the problem!

Comment: when you call `acceptor.async_accept`, you pass a reference to a socket, that may be destroyed before the completion `on_accept_connection` is called. I do not know if this is the cause of your problems, but it is definitifly a serious error. Maybe you'd rather use the `async_accept` that returns a connected socket into the completion.

Comment: @JakobStark: This is a shared pointer, so there is no reason for it to be destroyed.

Comment: A `shared_ptr` destroyes the underlying object, as soon as the last copy of the pointer goes out of scope. You are passing `*m_nextConnection` to `async_accept`. This passes a raw reference of the underlying object to the function. The pointer (and with it the socket object, because the smart pointer has not been copied) is destroyed when `do_accept_connection` returns.

Comment: @JakobStark: No, `m_nextConnection`is declared global, so it wil never be deleted. But I'd like to try the `async_accept` creating the socket itself anyway, maybe the one I'm using has a bug. Do you have any example? I can't find out how to correctly declare `on_accept_connection` and bind it...

Comment: @JakobStark: Got it from ChatGPT....makes no difference, bug is still there under Linux.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the global variable. There is an example in the [asio reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/async_accept/overload3.html). A signature of `void accept_handler(const boost::system::error_code& error,
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket peer)` should do. No need for a bind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server thread was modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44500924/85371). The comment is telling:

```
// don't break, keep looping, else we may exit before a connection is actually established
```

This is not true. The reason you see it exit before the connection is established is because the IO service runs out of work. Since you let the service run out of work, looping makes zero sense, unless you [actually use `restart()`](https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/run/overload1.html):

> Subsequent calls to `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()` or `poll_one()` will return immediately unless there is a prior call to `restart()`

So, the real fix is to keep the loop as it was intended but place work before starting it, e.g. changing

```
std::thread serverThread(server_thread_func, std::ref(ioc));
do_accept_connection(m_acceptor, ioc);
```

To

```
do_accept_connection(m_acceptor, ioc);
std::thread serverThread(server_thread_func, std::ref(ioc));
```

### Other Issues

The global connection variable **is** a problem, especially once you accept more than 1 connection. Fix it by not using a global, e.g.:

```
void on_accept_connection(std::error_code ec, std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> s) {
    if (!ec)
        std::cout << "SERVER ACCEPTED CONNECTION from " << s->remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Reader connection error " << ec << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
}

void do_accept_connection(tcp::acceptor& acceptor, asio::io_context& service) {
    auto s = std::make_shared<tcp::socket>(service);
    acceptor.async_accept(*s, bind(on_accept_connection, _1, s));
}
```

Note how we bind the shared pointer into the completion handler, to keep it alive.

This already works: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df135c6936c5e37e

```
Connecting socket...
Connected socket
SERVER ACCEPTED CONNECTION from 127.0.0.1:45958
[eventloop] exit
Closing socket
```

### Fixing Everything

However, you should take the overload that moves the socket, use builtin thread pool, not use a second io service, use `io_context` instead of the deprecated `io_service` and other stuff like not use unncessary raw pointers, `boost::bind` (or bind at all) and `boost::thread`, passing around execution contexts instead of executors etc.: **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/940f3f06cdd68f4c)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

void on_accept_connection(std::error_code ec, tcp::socket s) {
    if (!ec)
        std::cout << "Accepted from " << s.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << std::endl;
}

void accept_loop(tcp::acceptor& acc) {
    acc.async_accept(make_strand(acc.get_executor()), on_accept_connection);
}

int main() {
    tcp::endpoint ep{{}, 1900};
    using std::this_thread::sleep_for;

    asio::thread_pool ioc(1);

    tcp::acceptor listener{ioc, ep};
    accept_loop(listener);

    sleep_for(500ms);

    {
        // start client:
        tcp::socket socket(ioc);

        std::cout << "Connecting socket..." << std::endl;
        socket.connect(ep);
        std::cout << "Connected socket" << std::endl;

        sleep_for(500ms);
        std::cout << "Closing socket" << std::endl;
    }

    ioc.join();
}
```

Printing

```
Connecting socket...
Connected socket
Accepted from 127.0.0.1:47014
Closing socket
```

### Bonus

To make it complete, actually make `accept_loop` loop:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2afbb2b4159af418)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using boost::system::error_code;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

struct session : std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {
    session(tcp::socket s) : s_(std::move(s)) {}

    void run() {
        std::cout << "Session from " << s_.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
        async_write(s_,
                    asio::buffer(message_), //
                    consign(asio::detached, shared_from_this()));
    }

  private:
    tcp::socket s_;
    std::string message_ = "Hello from server\n";
};

struct listener {
    listener(tcp::endpoint ep) : acc_(ioc_, ep) { accept_loop(); }

  private:
    asio::thread_pool ioc_{1};
    tcp::acceptor     acc_;

    void accept_loop() {
        acc_.async_accept(make_strand(acc_.get_executor()), [this](error_code ec, tcp::socket s) {
            if (!ec) {
                std::make_shared<session>(std::move(s))->run();
                accept_loop();
            } else
                std::cout << std::endl;
        });
    }
};

int main() {
    tcp::endpoint ep{{}, 1900};
    listener      server(ep);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(50ms);

    for (auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        tcp::iostream is(ep);
        std::cout << "Connected: " << is.rdbuf() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Printing e.g.

```
Connected: Session from 127.0.0.1:48586
Hello from server

Connected: Session from 127.0.0.1:48588
Hello from server

Connected: Session from 127.0.0.1:48590
Hello from server

Connected: Session from 127.0.0.1:48592
Hello from server

Connected: Session from 127.0.0.1:48594
Hello from server

Connected: Session from 127.0.0.1:48596
Hello from server

Connected: Session from 127.0.0.1:48598
Hello from server

Connected: Session from 127.0.0.1:48600
Hello from server

Connected: Session from 127.0.0.1:48602
Hello from server

Connected: Session from 127.0.0.1:48604
Hello from server
```

Comment: Because your client seems to favor sync code, would you like to have a synchronous session handler: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbda43d54cc16131 live interactive demo https://i.imgur.com/k78fy2X.mp4

Comment: Thank you so much. Just adding `restart()` before `run()` in `server_thread_func` fixed the issue. I'll go with this fix for now and consider other changes to enhance the code later.