Problem "Connection lost" in AMQP-CPP with boost asio
I use the AMQP-CPP library (a C++ wrapper for RabbitMQ) to create a RPC server and several clients. For event loop I use boost Asio and run it inside a std::thread.
I implemented class-wrapper RabbitMQ which takes care about all the stuff related to RabbitMQ routines - creating queue, exchange, servers, clients etc.
In one test case I repeat a chunk of code with creating RPC client and connecting it to the server 1000 times. This test case fail with error "Channel open error - connection lost" in random moments (it can fail on iteration 66, 533 etc) and random step (when queue was declared, after server's response was received).
Here is code for test case with a problem:
RabbitMQ srv_rabbitmq(uri);

srv_rabbitmq.start();
// declare queue, exchange, bind it
auto rpc_server = srv_rabbitmq.make_rpc_server(server_config, rpc_server_cb);

auto rabbit_f = [&client_config, &request]() {
    try {
        RabbitMQ rabbitmq(uri);
        rabbitmq.start();
        auto rpc_client = rabbitmq.make_rpc_client(client_config);
        auto response = rpc_client->send_request(request);
        ASSERT_EQ(response.Body, request.Body);
    } TEST_CATCH
};
for (auto i = 0; i < test_count; ++i) {
    rabbit_f();        
    std::cout << "Successfully connected " << (i + 1) << "/" << test_count << std::endl;
}

Code of method start() where I start thread with event loop
void RabbitMQ::start() {
    {
        // some code
        m_handler = std::make_unique<AMQP::LibBoostAsioHandler>(service);
        m_connection = std::make_shared<AMQP::TcpConnection>(m_handler.get(), AMQP::Address(m_uri));
    }    
    m_working_thread = std::thread([&] {        
        // some code
        while(service.run());    
    });
}

Code of destructor and method stop() in class RabbitMQ:
RabbitMQ::~RabbitMQ() {
    if (m_working_thread.joinable()) {
        stop();        
        m_working_thread.join();
    }    
    if (!service.stopped()) {
        m_handler.reset();
    }
}

void RabbitMQ::stop() {
    if (m_is_run) {
        service.stop();
        m_connection->close();
        service.reset();
    }
}

Here are logs from tests
Successfully connected 65/1000
RabbitMQ RPC Client - success declare queue
[2024-04-18 17:05:51.877] [error] "caller":"/home/vlad/Maynitek/rabbitmq-lib/src/RabbitMQ/RPC/Client.cpp:137","error":"connection lost","exchange":"e.test.rpc","func":"operator()","msg":"RabbitMQ RPC Client - error","queue":"\u0010>\u0000XJw\u0000\u0000\u000b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000routing_key\u0000Hw","routing_key":"","rpc_namespace":"mongoose::test"

What can be the problem here?

I fail to see why this is asio-tagged? Ironically there's nothing about the asio stuff. The code doesn't even declare service, so technically we can only guess it might be asio::io_context. Other than that everything is RabbitMQ, looks like? Anyways, while (service.run()); is useless by definition: service.run() will only return when it ran out of work and subsequent invocations will have no effect (until the service is reset). See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/44500924/85371 by the way

@sehe Thank you for reply. I initialize service in constructor of class RabbitMQ, just forgot to present it's code in my question. Btw thanks for while (service.run());. I already figured this out. I will check the like you provided.
