Boost async handler not being called
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
I am building a client server pair (simple echo server currently) and think I must have a design issue The following code works on my server side but does not work on my client side.
My handshake function is this (on the server side I do bssl::stream_base::server) :
void CSClient::handshake() {
    mSocket.async_handshake(bssl::stream_base::client,
                            std::bind(&CSClient::handleHandshake, this, std::placeholders::_1));
}

My handler is this:
void CSClient::handleHandshake(bsys::error_code const& ec) {
    if (!ec) {
        // allow only once at a time
        startClientThreadMxt.lock();
        std::thread clientThread(&CSClient::startClientThread, this, std::move(mSocket));
        clientThread.join();
        // thread started
        startClientThreadMxt.unlock();
    } else {
        std::string msg{"Handshake failed: "};
        msg += ec.what();
        DUAL_LOG_FATAL_MSG(mLog, mDebugLog, msg);
        exit(FATAL_ERROR_SSL_HANDSHAKE_FAILED);
    }
}

void CSClient::startClientThread(bssl::stream<bip::tcp::socket> socket) {
    std::make_shared<CSClientThread>std::move(socket),
                std::bind(&CSClient::pollIOContext,this),
        &mShutdown, mLog,mDebugLog)->start();
}

The thread kicks off successfully and this is my start routine is this:
void CSClientThread::start() {
    // if we are shutting down, this doesn't need to be done
    if (*mShutdown) {
        return;
    }
    std::cout << "Enter input: ";
    char buffer[1024];
    std::cin.getline(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    bsys::error_code error{};
    int              len = std::strlen(buffer);
    if (Write(buffer, len, error)) {
        int length{0};
        if (Read(buffer, length, error)) {
            if (length) {
                std::cout << "Received: " << buffer << std::endl;
            } else {
                std::cout << "Zero length read" << std::endl;
            }
        } else {
            std::cout << "Error on Read: " << error.what() << std::endl;
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Error on Write: " << error.what() << std::endl;
    }

So you know the Write function is emulating a synchronous write with code checking for shutdown conditions here is the write function and related:
bool CSThreadBase::Write(void* buff, int length, bsys::error_code& ec) {
    ;
    // if we are already waiting don't wait for a second
    if (mAsyncWritePending) {
        length = 0;
        ec     = make_error_code(bsys::errc::operation_not_permitted);
        return false;
    }

    bool rtncde{false};
    if (asyncWrite(ec, buff, length)) {
        auto& io_context = mSocket.get_executor().context();

        rtncde = waitForAsyncWrite();
    }

    ec = mIOEc;

    return true;
}

bool CSThreadBase::asyncWrite(bsys::error_code const& ec, void* buff, std::size_t length) {
    // if we are already waiting to write don't do another
    if (mAsyncWritePending) {
        DUAL_LOG_TRACE_MSG(mLog, mDebugLog, "Exit CSServerThread::doWrite()");
        return false;
    }

    mAsyncWritePending = true;

    auto self(shared_from_this());
    basio::async_write(
        mSocket, basio::buffer(buff, length),
        std::bind(&CSThreadBase::handleAsyncWrite, self, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));

    return true;
}

void CSThreadBase::handleAsyncWrite(bsys::error_code const& ec, std::size_t length) {
    std::cerr << "Entered handleAsyncWrite" << std::endl;
    if (!ec) {
        mWriteLength       = length;
        mIOEc              = ec;
        mAsyncWritePending = false;
    } else {
        mIOEc = ec;
        std::string msg{"handleAsyncWrite Error "};
        msg += ec.what();
        DUAL_LOG_ERROR_MSG(mLog, mDebugLog, msg);
    }
}

bool CSThreadBase::waitForAsyncWrite() {
    while (mAsyncWritePending && !isShuttingDown()) {
        std::this_thread::yield();
    }
    return getIOStatus(mWriteLength);
}

My issue appears to be the handleAsyncWrite which sets mAsyncWritePending to false is not getting called. I suspect I must have a design issue, but like I mentioned this code works in my server, which is actually receiving the write and doing its side.
I have tried adding a function that checks that the io_context is still running and it appears to be.  at least io_context.stopped() is false.
I am fairly new to C++ and boost asio.  And am sure there are better ways to implement this. I have separating the handlers from the async calls so they can be overridden in later versions of this project. And am certain that the yield() isn't the best way to implement this wait.  But for now I'm mostly just trying to understand how things work.

if I just read over this stuff quickly, I'm getting the suspicion that you are waiting for your thread to finish (you are calling join() on it), while your thread is not running the io_context. So, you are queuing your write and read calls, but they aren't ever processed...

I was thinking that the yield() in the wait loop would allow the main thread, where the io_service runs to allow the handler to get called.  Am I wrong in this?  I will try putting a loop around the io_context.run() (including the io_context.restart())  I did try using detatch() instead,and the io_context.run() must have finished, because the main thread finished and killed the child.

The code is significantly overcomplicated with many opportunities for errors. I'd appreciate if you just posted a full self-contained example so we can see what you're actually trying to achieve. It's easier to help with that, than to help you debug problems that (a) aren't reproducible from the code (b) do not need to exist.

@ChristianStieber, you were correct, I changed the join to detatch, and put a loop around the io_context.run() and it executed correctly.  Thank you.  Is it possible to mark your comment as the answer?

That's pretty bad advice. Friends don't let friends detach threads willy nilly. Also, if you have a loop around io_context.run() you're doing things wrong. See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_85_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/restart.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500818/should-the-exception-thrown-by-boostasioio-servicerun-be-caught

This is what I baked from the bits shown and bits missing https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3406a4b569baf32. It's too little to go on. I'd be happy to look further if I knew what the code was trying to do. I smell a lot of Java style experience, but very little C++ experience. Everything can (and should) be an order of magnitude simpler, is my feeling.

@TomDavidson there are a lot more problems than just this; it was merely the immediately visible thing. I kind of get where the thread comes from -- you can't combine cin with the async stuff -- but it's clearly not how I would have done it. Also, at the very least, your loop with the yield should be a condition variable, but that just fixes an implementation problem of something that I still think is bad to start with...

@sehe you are probably right, this is a learning project for me, it started out as a simple synchronous echo server and client, then I went to boost ASIO when I wanted to add SSL, then became asynchronous/multithreaded, I've added an admin thread to shut down my server from the console, next will be adding structured messages instead of just a buffer, then add validation of a user.  My goal is to have a client server base that I can use for some 'real' client server stuff.  As I learn I go back and restucture where I find new/better ways of doing things.

@ChristianStieber, the cin stuff was in the original boost tutorial, its simply there because I'm not worried about it at the moment, I kept the easy way of getting something to echo and print the echo.  Like I said I'm still learning and at the moment I'm just playing.  It will probably undergo multiple complete restructuring before I get to my end state.  I do appreciate the advice though.  A couple of references have been added by sehe so I will investigate them before deciding if/what/how a rewrite is in the works.

@TomDavidson if you have a github link e.g. I could have a look

@sehe I have one, I don't yet know how to use it :(.  For now I am just playing, thank you for the kind offer
